# Replace HTML entities between divs and only between divs

Tags: php, string, wordpress, replace

Given the following string:

```
asd &nbsp; <div> def &nbsp; foo &nbsp; </div> ghi &nbsp; <div> moo &nbsp; </div>
```

I want to remove all of the `&nbsp;`'s that are within `<div>`s, resulting in:

```
asd &nbsp; <div> def  foo  </div> ghi &nbsp; <div> moo  </div>
```

I can use any standard PHP stuff, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem. I couldn't figure out how to keep the contents inside the `<div>`s while removing the `&nbsp;`

The reason why I need this is because WordPress's content filter adds `&nbsp;` under strange situations. I can't simply remove all `&nbsp;` because they might've been specifically entered by the user, but I need to remove all of them within the element that's having display problems caused by them

Comment: Doing this in a single regex is hard. It's easier to use preg_replace_callback() to find the text between `<div>` and `</div>`, then run it through str_replace() inside the callback function. The key here is use ungreedy matching.

Comment: @cleong That's what I thought, problem is preg_replace_callback receives all of the matches as an array and loses what's in between. That's where I got stuck

Comment: @2unco What do you mean you lose what's in between? Are you capturing it? The regexp ought to look something like `/(<div.*?>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/`. The open tag will be in element 1, what's inside in element 2, and the end tag in element 3.

Comment: it would be saner to find out why WP adds the entities then and fix that instead of curing the symptoms. Besides, why not just set the entire blog to UTF-8 and don't use entities at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
      $text = "asd &nbsp; <div> def &nbsp; </div> ghi &nbsp; <div> moo &nbsp; </div>";
      echo preg_replace_callback(
                "#<div(.*?)>(.*?&nbsp;.*?)</div>#i",
                "filter_nbsp",
                $text);

                function filter_nbsp($matches)
    {

      return "<div".$matches[1].">" . str_replace("&nbsp;","",$matches[2]) . "</div>";
    }
```

That should work for entities between div elements closed as `</div>`,

output

```
asd &nbsp; <div> def  </div> ghi &nbsp; <div> moo  </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this works as mentioned? It's greedy, wouldn't it therefore get rid of the &nbsp; in between the two divs?

Answer (score 1):

The following works in your case:

```
$str = "asd &nbsp; <div> def &nbsp; </div> ghi &nbsp; <div> moo &nbsp; </div>";
$res = preg_replace("%<div>(.*?)&nbsp;(.*?)</div>%", "<div>$1$2</div>", $str);
```

But beware of some facts:

- It won't work if the divs have attributes;
- It won't work as expected if the divs are nested;
- It applies the replacement of a `&nbsp;` only one time, so multiple `&nbsp;`s inside divs are untouched.

So the abovementioned replacement is not a good solution at all. It's way better to first find the div tags with a (XML) parser function and then replace all `&nbsp;`s.

Comment: Ahh I needed multiple &nbsp;s in the same. Sorry about that :( I'll add it to the problem description. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

simple_html_dom

```
    $html = str_get_html('asd &nbsp; <div> def &nbsp; </div> ghi &nbsp; <div> moo &nbsp; </div>');

foreach($html->find('div') as $element) {
      $a = $element->plaintext;
      $element->innertext = preg_replace('{\&nbsp;}','',$a);
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: if you suggest non-native libraries, at least explain what they are and where to get them. Also note that the OP said he can use "any standard PHP stuff" which simplehmtldom is not.